# How to get all information in firebase to be shown on the screen

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYbYZ.png)I am trying to get the following information to be shown on the screen but am not getting the genre to be shown. I think my code should work but it is only displaying the user's name..I I am not sure where I went wrong with the following code because I can insert the information to the database successfully but just can't retrieve all information..

```
 public class MainActivity  extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText editTextName;
    Spinner spinnerGenres;
    Button buttonAdd;

    DatabaseReference databaseArtists;

    ListView listViewArtists;

    List<Artist> artistList;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setProjectId("Faourite Place in Melbourne")
                .setApplicationId("")
                .setApiKey("")

                // setStorageBucket(...)
                .build();


        databaseArtists = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://favourite-place-in-melbourne.firebaseio.com/").getReference();

        editTextName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
        buttonAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonAddArtist);
        spinnerGenres = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerGenres);

        listViewArtists = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewArtists);

        artistList = new ArrayList<>();

        buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               addArtist();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        databaseArtists.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                artistList.clear();

               for(DataSnapshot artistSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                   Artist artist = artistSnapshot.getValue(Artist.class);

                   artistList.add(artist);
               }

                ArtistList adapter = new ArtistList(MainActivity.this, artistList);
               listViewArtists.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void addArtist() {
        String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
        String genre = spinnerGenres.getSelectedItem().toString();

        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
           String id = databaseArtists.push().getKey();

           Artist user = new Artist(id, name, genre);
           databaseArtists.child(id).setValue(user);

           Toast.makeText(this, "Favourite Places added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this,"You should enter a name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please log the artist and check what data your getting

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot.

Comment: I think it might be my background colour... not sure

Comment: will check it out

Comment: It is not my background but I will upload a picture of my screenshot to show you guys what is showing

Comment: I will also upload my picture of my firebase database

Comment: The problem was with my xml file... the orientation should be set to vertical instead of horizontal but there is another problem here and I can't scoll my listview smoothly what can I do?